# How could droids (specifically BB-8 and R2-D2) communicate long-distance?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens

How could (for example) BB-8 and R2-D2 communicate with each other over long distances (on different planets)? Is it possible they could plug into terminals (remember in Episode III when R2-D2 plugs in to change the elevator floor) to send messages?

Do we have any evidence that BB-8 can connect to terminals, or would he be using differnt technology? etc.

Comment: Welcome to modern era my friend. Wireless technologies are new astromech norms.

Comment: BB-8 can connect to terminals, but not physically.

Comment: What evidence is there that they COULD communicate long-distance in the first place?

Comment: @SS3 is there in canon evidence of this? Thanks!

Comment: @DVK I don't know of any such evidence, I meant this question as a hypothetical.

Comment: @SS-3 Isn't there a Verizon or some other wireless carrier that shows BB-8 directly connecting to a terminal?

Comment: Thanks, https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8&client=ubuntu#q=verizon%20commercial%20bb8 brings some promising results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- They could communicate, there was special Resistance Network available to them. They connected to the network wirelessly.
- *The Force Awakens Visual Dictionary* says this of BB-8:

  > The BB-8 tracking mode, **which connects it to Resistance network**, was neglectfully disabled prior to its latest mission
- The official TFA novelization by Foster elaborates:

  > “How can I have committed such a devastating oversight?” the protocol droid continued. “When we sent Beebee-Ate off, it was my responsibility to perform his final checkout. Which I did, in most excellent and approved fashion. Except—except…” If a droid could have fallen to wailing, C-3PO would have done so on the spot. **“I forgot to activate his long-range tracking mode!** I must have assumed he would always be in the presence of that pilot and that therefore there would be no need. I deserve to have my memory wiped. Oh, Artoo, what am I to do? I wish you’d finally wake up, I need you now.”
- And then we see C-3PO alert the droid network on other planets:

  > “What would your advice be? No doubt you’d have an opinion about **sending a general alert to all our associate droids**, in the hope that one of them might encounter Beebee-Ate or his ident signal.” Two hands, one gold and one red, rose slightly in realization. “Why, that’s brilliant! I will do just that. Artoo, you’re a genius!”
- ... and one of them, on Takodana, responds:

  > Nearby, a small bipedal GA-97 droid who had been monitoring the pastime turned curiously to check the source of the excised limb. Though it initially focused on Rey, its attention was immediately drawn away from her and to the rotund droid at her side. Visual recognition ignited a small but very important internal sequence **that concluded with the GA-97 sending out a compressed signal that was bounced around, coded, decoded, encrypted, and flashed out into deep space**.
  >   **Where it very soon was picked up, decoded, and decrypted**, to become the impetus for an electronic shout of joy.

Comment: So would it be possible for 2 droids to send private messages to each other?

Comment: @ThomasShera - depends on how you define "Private". It's a Resistance network, so presumably, not completely private.

Comment: @thomas-shera as private as a phone call, or Facebook message, or a pilot's message to the control tower can be, I would presume. Everything can be intercepted, but it's noise unless you hold the decryption key or be able to crack it